# For TinyMCE editor - how to allow formatting paste

Tags: tinymce

Once copy paste any article or paragraph in editor that time, how to do the code for 'keep the formatting | Ok, paste text' in TinyMCE editor?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the 'Paste as Text' option by using the paste plugin: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/paste/

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to your HTML
  plugins: "paste",
  menubar: "edit",
  toolbar: "paste"
});
```

This will add the Paste as Text option under the Edit menu and a toolbar button by default. You can also have it paste as text by default.